# Using 'import * as' in a typescript component gives an error -

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to import a html template into a typescript **component** and its giving me an error. I'm using Angular 1.5.

The component looks like this...

```
import * as template from './home.template.html';
import { HomeController } from './home.controller';

export const HomeComponent = {
    bindings: {
        conf: '<',
    },
    controller: HomeController,
    template,
};
```

And thats added to the module like this...

```
import * as angular from 'angular';

import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

export const HomeModule = angular.module('home', [])
.component('home', HomeComponent);
```

And the error I am getting is...

> Argument of type '{ bindings: { conf: string;}; controller: typeof HomeCon...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IComponentOptions'.
>    Types of property 'template' are incompatible..
>      Type 'typeof '*.html'' is not assignable to type 'string | ((...args: any[]) => string) | (string | ((...args: any[]) => string))[]'.
>        Type 'typeof '*.html'' is not assignable to type '(string | ((...args: any[]) => string))[]'.
>          Property 'find' is missing in type 'typeof '*.html''.

If I add `template: template.toString()` to the HomeComponent it seems to work. But that doesn't feel right to me. Any other suggestions?

Comment: do you have any module declaration for html files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to import an HTML file as a string with TypeScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36649795/is-it-possible-to-import-an-html-file-as-a-string-with-typescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere in your type declarations you need to declare a module ending on .html

```
declare module '*.html' {
    const template: string;
    export default template;
}
```

with this declaration your code should run without another change

Comment: This is correct. But consider mentioning that the important statement will need to be updated because it's currently wrong