# Angular 5 - Load local file's raw data into variable

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

Pretty new to Angular/TypeScript, so sorry if this is obvious.

Using Angular 5, I'm making a service in which one of the endpoints must return a locally stored data file "as is".

Let's say this service is called `my-service`. The service file is therefore `my-service.service.ts`, and the local data file (in the same folder) is `my-service.service.data`, which contains data as text (format doesn't matter).

What I would like to do is have this service method:

```
getData(): Observable<string> {
    return of(data);
}
```

where `data` would simply be the text content of `my-service.service.data`, as a string.

A potential solution I found (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/36661720/965834) is the following:

```
declare module '*.data' {
    const content: string;
    export default content;
}
```

which would then be used like this:

```
import * as data from 'my-service.service.data';
```

but the `declare module` instruction doesn't seem to work anywhere within an Angular 5 project (including main.js), and always produces:

> error TS2664: Invalid module name in augmentation, module '*.data'
>   cannot be found.

(Same code seems to work in a simple .ts file within a non-angular project though.)

Now I could store the file within `assets/` and load it through Angular's HTTP client but I'd prefer keeping the file within my service folder as it just makes sense to have it there.

Thanks in advance for your help.