# Import HTML as string and test with Jest

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-jest

I'm using sveltekit and I can't use the files api to import html templates. So I decided to import by writing a module that imports the content of the document as a string (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36649795/is-it-possible-to-import-an-html-file-as-a-string-with-typescript)).

```
// src/global.d.ts

/// <reference types="@sveltejs/kit" />
declare module '*.html' {
  const content: string
  export default content
}
```

So far so good, but now I need to test the code and jest can't interpret the code.

```
● Test suite failed to run

Jest encountered an unexpected token

Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

Here's what you can do:
 • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
 • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
For information about custom transformations, see:
https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

Details:

/home/developer/workspace/src/assets/html/confirm_email.html:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){<!DOCTYPE html>
                                                                                  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

I don't understand how jest understands the .d.ts files... How do I get to test the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.Import html as string**

I solved the problem using another approach...

I'm using a resource of vite to import the html file as an asset, as can be seen [here in the documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#importing-asset-as-string)

```
import confirm_email_template from '../../../assets/html/confirm_email.html?raw'
```

**2.Test using Jest**

For production it works perfectly, but for unit testing the code breaks because Jest can't import the asset as a module.

So the second part of the problem was fixed (I don't know if this is the best practice) using asset mocks.

```
// jest.config.cjs

{
⋮
  moduleNameMapper: {
      ⋮
      '([a-zA-Z_ ]+\\.html)\\?raw$': '<rootDir>/__mocks/$1.cjs'
  }
⋮
}
```

To make it work, I created the following folder structure:

```
__mocks
      |
       confirm_email.html.cjs
       another_asset_mocked.html.cjs
```

The `confirm_email.html.cjs` looks like this:

```
// __mocks/confirm_email.html.cjs
module.exports = '<html>content<html>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you install @babel/plugin-transform-runtime"?

I share my config for jest/svelte-jester..

I have:

**jsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "$lib": ["src/lib"],
            "$lib/*": ["src/lib/*"]
        }
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.js", "src/**/*.svelte"],
    
}
```

**svelte.config.js**

```
 import vercel from '@sveltejs/adapter-vercel'

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
 
    kit: {
        adapter: vercel(),
        vite: {
            define: {
              'process.env': process.env,
            },
          },
     
     
    },
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.svelte$": ["svelte-jester", { "preprocess": true }]
      }
};

export default config;
```

**babel.config.json**

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", { "modules": "auto" }]
  ],
    "plugins": ["babel-plugin-transform-vite-meta-env","@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"]
}
```

**jest.config.js**

```
export default {
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
   "^.+\\.svelte$": "svelte-jester",
   
 },
 "moduleFileExtensions": ["svelte", "js"],
  "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect"]
 
 
  }
```

**and whole package.json**

```
{
  "name": "sveltekit",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "svelte-kit dev",
    "build": "svelte-kit build",
    "package": "svelte-kit package",
    "preview": "svelte-kit preview",
    "test": "jest src",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.12",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.16.8",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.17.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^1.29.1",
    "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^1.0.0-next.7",
    "@sveltejs/kit": "^1.0.0-next.215",
    "@sveltejs/svelte-virtual-list": "^3.0.1",
    "@testing-library/svelte": "^3.0.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.1",
    "babel-jest": "^27.4.6",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vite-meta-env": "^1.0.3",
    "jest": "^27.4.7",
    "postcss-load-config": "^3.1.1",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^2.5.1",
    "svelte": "^3.44.0",
    "svelte-jester": "^2.1.5",
    "svelte-lazy": "^1.0.12",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.8",
    "ts-jest": "^27.1.3"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fontsource/fira-mono": "^4.5.0",
    "@lukeed/uuid": "^2.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "cookie": "^0.4.1",
    "svelte-lazy-image": "^0.2.0",
    "swiper": "^8.0.3"
  },
  "testEnvironment": "jsdom"
}
```

I hope it will help you.I had a lot of troubles too with setting up jest..